# How to use the Slick generated Table <> apply, tupled, etc correctly?

Tags: scala, slick

I have a code generated model from Slick (3.1.1) and I knew I could do the following with it e.g.

```
val action = sql"""SELECT * FROM ${User.baseTableRow.tableName}""".as[UserRow].headOption
db.run(action)
```

but now getting a bit more involved with Slick I have the following query:

```
val selectAction = (for {
  linkedAccount <- LinkedAccount
  user <- User if user.id === sourceUser.id && user.id === linkedAccount.userId
} yield (targetUser.id, linkedAccount.providerKey, linkedAccount.providerPassword, linkedAccount.modified)).
  result.map(_.map(LinkedAccountRow.tupled))
```

The only way I could map the result tuple `(targetUser.id, linkedAccount.providerKey, linkedAccount.providerPassword, linkedAccount.modified)` to the appropriate case class `LinkedAccountRow` was using this ugly `.map(_.map(LinkedAccountRow.tupled))` ... and there should be a more elegant way to do this using the generated `<>`, `tupled` or?

Comment: what is ugly about `.map(_.map(LinkedAccountRow.tupled))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't see anything ugly in `.map(_.map(LinkedAccountRow.tupled))` but still this is not my preferred way to do it with slick.

One very important thing about writing Scala code is that your aim is not to write compact concise code but to write readable, simpler and easier to understand code.

I would have done it like following which is a little more code but is comparatively clearer,

```
val selectionAction = LinkedAccount
  .join(User)
  .on({ case (linkedAccount, user) =>
    user.id === sourceUser.id && user.id === linkedAccount.userId
  })
  .map({ case (linkedAccount, user) =>
    (targetUser.id, linkedAccount.providerKey, linkedAccount.providerPassword, linkedAccount.modified)
  })

val resultFuture = db.run(selectionAction)

val linkedAccountRowListFuture = resultFuture.map(seq => {
  seq.map(tuple => LinkedAccountRow.tupled(tuple)).toList
})
```